# How to use line-clamp with a input field

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display text on 4 lines within an input field, but nothing seems to work. Does line-clamp work with input or it's just a `p` tags thing?

```css
.line-clamp {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 4;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Edit:** The user can write a note title in the input field and if the title is too long that's where the line-clamp should start working

Comment: input is only one line and trying to clamp a user input is a very bad UX idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use textarea instead of input and limit the size by `rows` and `cols` attribute

```
<textarea rows="3" ></textarea>
```

Comment: i need the input because its part of a form and if the user change the data inside the input.it'll make an ajax request to an API. Is it possible to hide an input between a p tag? Would that work?

Comment: textarea can also be used as form field.